# A word for counting the prisoners

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or a phrase for counting the prisoners in a jail to see if anyone is missing. Is *prisoner count* a valid term?

Answer (score 3):

The term you are seeking is ***roll call***, which applies to any process in which a list of names is checked against the people present.

Answer (score 3):

***[Headcount or head count](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/headcount)***:

> - The act of counting people in a particular group. (AHD)

[Head count reveals prisoner's escape](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2009-07-23/head-count-reveals-prisoners-escape/1363638):

> - Robert John Dwight, 33, was found to be missing during a head count by prison officers at Silverwater jail about 9.00pm AEST yesterday.

(www.abc.net.au/news)